# responsible_user_id обязательное поле при создании сделки в amocrm api?

Tags: crm

подскажите, обязательно ли поле `responsible_user_id`  в создании сделки через amocrm api?

Как я понял, оно назначает ответственного юзера за сделку, а если мне нужно, чтобы заявка падала в не разобранное и перетащив ее менеджер становится ответственным за нее, как лучше это организовать?

Answer (score 0):

если поле не задано - ответственный будет то из под какого аккаунта создали сделку (чей ключ к API)